# Textmate unable to find Mercurial hg

Tags: mercurial, textmate

When I attempt to run Mercurial diff from within Textmate, I get an error "Couldn't find hg."

hg works from the command line and is in my path.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is shown when you issue `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /opt/local/bin:
/opt/local/sbin:
/usr/bin:/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/X11/bin:
/usr/local/bin:

Answer (score 0):

I updated Textmate PATH shell variable to include /usr/local/bin/ and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the TM_HG variable and simply add /usr/local/bin/ to the PATH variable in the Textmate-Preferences.

For example my PATH looks like: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/

KR Bijan